# How do I create instances of a class within that class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So we have two classes: `Test` and `TestManager`. Every `Test` object should have its manager, instantiated on its `__init__` function. Also, in order to create a `TestManager` object, you need to pass a `Test` instance to it.

How can we do that? I have this, but doesn't work:

```
class SubTest:
    def __init__(self, test):
        print(test.getText())

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello world!"
        SubTest(Test) # In Java this would be something like 'new SubTest(this);'

    def getText(self):
        return self.text

Test()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing Test to SubTest, try passing self. i.e. SubTest(self)

Comment: Note that after you fix `SubTest(Test)` to `SubTest(self)`, you create an instance of SubTest class and then throw it away.

Comment: Thanks! Passing 'self' is the right one. Looks like also works in other functions of the class, not only in the `__init__()`.

Comment: Your question should be how to deal with circular dependencies between two classes. That would probably lead you to better solutions.

Comment: Your question should be how to deal with circular dependencies between two classes. That would probably lead you to better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a Test to SubTest, refer to the class as 'self', meaning your code should look a little something like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello world!"
        SubTest(self) # Passing self, instead of 'Test'
```

And your full code like this:

```
class SubTest:
    def __init__(self, test):
        print(test.getText())

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello world!"
        SubTest(self)

    def getText(self):
        return self.text

Test()
```